# Representation of point at infinity of elliptic curves in Affine space

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, elliptic-curves, projective-geometry, projective-space

I am self reading theory of elliptic curves over finite fields. The following question has come to my mind.

Let $E$ be Weierstrass form of an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_p$, the point at infinity of $E$ in the projective space of $E$ is $(0,1,0)$. Can we represent this point at infinity of $E$ as a point in $\mathbb{F}_q \times \mathbb{F}_q$?

If anyone can provide any reference regarding this will be of great help.

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is an "affine equation" of an elliptic curve, e.g. in short Weierstraß form (in characteristic not $2,3$ we can arrange for this form):$$y^2 =x^3 +ax+b\ ,$$and a corresponding "affine" point is a point $(x,y,)\in\Bbb F_p\times \Bbb F_p$ which satisfies this equation. However, the right (projective) object is the set of all $[x:y:z]$, $x,y,z\in\Bbb F_p$ not all zero satisfying the homogenized version:$$y^2z = x^3+ axz^2+bz^3\ .$$Two such projective coordinates are equal if the vectors build out of the coordinates differ by a scalar multiple. One can "norm" $z=1$, except for $(0,1,0)$.

Comment: One can also take a view from an other affine perspective, e.g. by norming $y=1$, and thus losing those (possibly three) points with $y=0$, then the equation becomes:$$z=x^3+axz^2+bz^3\ ,$$ and an affine point of this chart perspective corresponds to the point $[x:1:z]$, but nobody publishes or burns in chips formulas for this equation. So for short, better take a structural look at the elliptic curve as a projective equation, see that it misses one point when restricting to the $(x,y)$-world.

Comment: We can't represent the point at infinity  in affine space and so we take it to projective space and understand the concept,right?

Comment: Yes, the projective space is the right algebraic object to work inside. Homogeneous polynomials define algebraic sets (varieties) like lines, quadrics, cubics, ... and from the algebraic point of view we solve "the same" algebraic equations. For instance, compare the equation of an affine line like $ax+by+c=0$ with the equation of a projective line, $ax+by+cz=0$. From the point of view of the complexity we have the same situation. Adding one more equation leads to a system with finitely many solutions. But in the projective setting we will "not miss" any point(s). (Here those with $z=0$.)